# BufferedImage for loop to pixelate

Tags: java, image, image-processing, awt, bufferedimage

As you can see I'm trying to write a method to pixelate a buffered image.  I've debugged all methods within this one that I call, splitARGB works correctly as well as combineARGB.
I have global variables for storing the splitARGB values (alpha,reds,greens,blues).  My problem seems to be that when running through the interior loops it continually gets the same aRGB value (at first they're different but eventually it just starts spitting out the same value) and then when I check out the image after it's done, it has 0 changes.

I have a few other methods which work perfectly and they call the same methods (splitARGB, combineARGB) and they work fine so I'm doing something wrong with this.  All help appreciated.

```
public static BufferedImage pixelate(BufferedImage imgt) {
    //vars
    int tempARGB = 0;
    int avgAlpha = 0;
    int avgRed = 0;
    int avgGreen = 0;
    int avgBlue = 0;
    int interval = 70;

    //every 2 Y pixels, iterate through the X line
    for (int y = 0; y < (imgt.getHeight() - interval); y = y + interval) {
        for (int x = 0; x < (imgt.getWidth() - interval); x = x + interval) {

            //interior pixel group loop
            for (int yloop = 0; yloop < interval; yloop++) {
                for (int xloop = 0; xloop < interval; xloop++) {

                    tempARGB = imgt.getRGB(yloop, xloop);
                    //System.out.println("XLOOP VAL:" + xloop);
                    //System.out.println("YLOOP VAL:" + yloop);
                    //System.out.println("TEMPARGB:" + tempARGB);
                    splitARGB(tempARGB);
                    avgAlpha = avgAlpha + alpha;
                    avgRed = avgRed + reds;
                    avgGreen = avgGreen + greens;
                    avgBlue = avgBlue + blues;
                }
            }
            //Average the values
            avgAlpha = avgAlpha / interval;
            avgRed = avgRed / interval;
            avgGreen = avgGreen / interval;
            avgBlue = avgBlue / interval;
            combineARGB(avgAlpha, avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue);
            System.out.println("New RGB:" + newRGB);

            //loop again to assign the values
            for (int yloop2 = 0; yloop2 < interval; yloop2++) {
                for (int xloop2 = 0; xloop2 < interval; xloop2++) {
                    imgt.setRGB(xloop2, yloop2, newRGB);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return imgt;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If possible, I would recommend that you `extend` BufferedImage; making a function to pixelate the image seems like functional, rather than Object-Oriented, programming.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one issue may be that in your interior loop, you keep checking the same values-- that is, each time you start that loop you're starting at 0 because you assigned yloop and xloop to be 0 **in** the loop declaration. Thus, every time you enter this loop, you're just going to check values 0 through interval. Same thing when you are setting the values. You should assign these values outside of all the loops, that way you can maintain your (x,y)index in the image instead of iterating over the same group.